# php explode string with links

Tags: php, explode

I have string with links, example -

```
$d = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/flight-formation.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/cat-nose.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/golden-hour.jpg';
```

How to explode the string to get the links by one?

Comment: Is it always images (jpg)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separator of some sort to use explode. Your best option would probably be to explode on "http", then restore it to the front of each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode('https://', $d);`. But I think the best way is to control how you got this string in the first time and add to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a space between them with str_replace and trim off the leading space that str_replace creates.
Then you have a string that can be easily exploded as normal.

```
$d = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/flight-formation.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/cat-nose.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/golden-hour.jpg';
$d = trim(str_replace("http", " http", $d));
$arr = explode(" ", $d);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(68) "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/flight-formation.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(60) "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/cat-nose.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(60) "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpg"
  [3]=>
  string(60) "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg"
  [4]=>
  string(63) "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/golden-hour.jpg"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/l7DRM